# Ctrl-C in a rlwrap command substitution stops echo

Tags: sh, sigint, rlwrap

I'm using something like this in a script:

```
REPLY=$(rlwrap head -n 1)
```

Actually with more options but that suffices to reproduce the issue. It works perfectly for my purposes... as long as I don't press Ctrl-C to quit. If I do, input echo stops on the terminal and the only way I've found to restore it is to blindly type `reset`.

The `-I` flag didn't help. I also tried this:

```
rlwrap head -n 1 | REPLY=$(cat)
```

but then REPLY wasn't set when I pressed Enter. <del>I've tried in both bash and dash, with identical results</del> EDIT: Sorry, due to a typo on the shebang, dash was not being executed. It works correctly in dash.

How can I set a variable to the output of `rlwrap` and be able to interrupt without losing input echo? Also out of curiosity, does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about dash. It actually works fine under dash, therefore my solution was to stop using bash-specific features in the script and switch it to dash.

**Update:** Later I found that using this as the shebang makes it work with bash too:

```
#!/bin/bash --noediting
```

which basically disables readline for bash.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `rlwrap` within a `$(...)` construct is correct. That you can do this is part of `rlwrap`'s "transparency": whatever works with `<command>` should also work with `rlwrap <command>`.

I cannot reproduce the problem on any of my systems.

This means you found a bug. You already posted [an issue](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/93) on the `rlwrap` Github site.

Edit: `strace`ing `rlwrap` on two systems, of which only one displays the bug, doesn't show any significant differences, so we conclude that this is probably not a `rlwrap` problem.

Comment: Thanks. I may have found a bug, but I'm still not sure it's an rlwrap bug, and whatever the outcome, I'd like to know if there's a workaround for such a situations. I'm a bit surprised that setting a variable in a pipe didn't work. Either way, I'm going to help you narrow it down.